# Bug in FireAlarm showing private API key

Tags: discussion, api

I just happened upon the FireAlarm chat room and noticed [this message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36456770#36456770)

Just tried the [URL][2] that was in the exception message, and it seems as though I can crawl questions with that API key...

How bad is this? I don't know the standard procedure for reporting these incidents

[2]: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/2414660?key=HNA2dbrFtyTZxeHN6rThNg((&filter=!-*f(6rOFHc24&site=stackoverflow

Comment: FireAlarm is a third-party app which runs off of the Stack Overflow API, so informing the maintainers would be the right approach.  It isn't a bug per se on Stack Overflow.

Comment: (bot's maintainer here) The API key isn't "private". It is completely safe exposing the API key in error messages. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @AshishAhuja ok cool. Closing

Answer (score 4):

> How bad is this?

I don't think it's devastating that an API key gets leaked, as API keys alone provide read-only access with per-IP quotas - to impersonate users with write access you would need an access token as well.

As for who to contact, the owner(s) of the key would be the best person/people to notify. In this case, you should contact [NobodyNada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476191/nobodynada) and [Ashish Ahuja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4688119/ashish-ahuja), the current maintainers of FireAlarm, who would then decide if a new API key should be created.

Comment: The source for FireAlarm is on GitHub, including the API key... So this cannot be a big concern.

Comment: In the registration page for an app on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) this is the comment for the Key field: *This is not considered a secret, and may be safely embed in client side code or distributed binaries.*. Compare that with the Client Secret field that is also found on the registered app page: *This **must** be kept secret. Do not embed it in client side code or binaries you intend to distribute. If you need client side authentication, use the implicit OAuth 2.0 flow.* That field also offers an reset link so you can generate a new client secret.

Comment: (bot's maintainer here) You don't need to create a new API key. The API key is not something _secret_ like rene said. _Most_ bots have the API key on the web, and even the registration page on SA says that it is not a secret. It _would_ be a problem if someone used our API key because that would deplete the bot's quota, but till now nothing has happened and I don't think we need to worry.

Comment: @Ashish The quota's per-IP, so it wouldn't do anything to our quota.

Comment: @NobodyNada ah, right. Forgot about that >_<